# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to R.string

Tags: java, android, string

I am new so forgive my primitive question, I am really not getting this. I am simply creating this array on my main activity while doing a tutorial and I get an error

```
package com.TaskReminder;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);
    string[] items = new string[]{"aa","bb"};
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,R.id.text1,items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}
```

and the error on my string array is :

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Line breakpoint:ReminderListActivity [line: 14] - 
>        onCreate(Bundle)
>
> **- Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to R.string**

what's exactly happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy fix, the String type needs to be capitalized.

```
string[] items = new string[]{"aa","bb"};
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,R.id.text1,items);
```

Becomes:

```
String[] items = new String[]{"aa","bb"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,R.id.text1,items);
```

@gt_ebuddy is right as well, remove this line:

import android.R.string;

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is the simplest way to import classes automatically, but it sometimes leads you astray when it tries to import anything from your package's R file.

Comment: Thanks !! I can't describe how dumb I feel, my programming is getting rusty :P gotta dive in !!

Answer (score 4):

Remove the import. and be happy.

```
import android.R.string;
```

And note that

- It should be `String`. Not `string`
- `String` class is defined in package `java.lang` and you will never require to import this package because they are automatically imported into every java program. [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html)  says  `"Package java.lang : Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language."`

Comment: I gave you an upvote and combined our answers (with due credit), since I hadn't noticed the erroneous import line at first.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `import android.R.string;`. I guess you have done that because of error shown on that line string should be in your `R.java` file it is automatically generated do not modify it Clean your project and build again Hope it works !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] items = new string[]{"aa","bb"};
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,R.id.text1,items);
```

change this to

```
String[] items = new String[]{"aa","bb"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,R.id.text1,items)
```