# Cannot convert from int to String from R.java

Tags: java, android

I have a Dashboard.java file where I use strings.xml parsed in R.java auto generated file.

When I try to do:

```
    public String BASE_URL = R.string.BASE_URL;
```

Naturally will tell Cannot convert from int to String.

But that's what will be chosen from string.xml for the translation.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: to extract the string for string.xml in the runtime for locale translation

Comment: You might see this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812121/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-string-to-r-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use This

```
String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.BASE_URL);
```

or you can copy from the code below:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.BASE_URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Resources res = getResources();
     String url = res.getString(R.string.hello_world);
     EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     et.setText(url);
```